# deleting all old ecr images for a particular branch

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, devops, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I want have some git branch deployments. For a particular branch, I want to keep the latest (sorted by imagePushedAt) and delete the remaining. This is what I am trying:

```
image_tags_json=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name bi-dagster --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].[imageTags[], imagePushedAt]' --output json)

# Check if there are any image tags returned
if [[ $(echo "$image_tags_json" | jq -r 'length') -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No image tags found."
    exit 1
fi

# Extract image tags containing the branch name along with timestamps
branch_image_tags=$(echo "$image_tags_json" | jq -r --arg branch "$branch_name" '.[] | select(.[0] | arrays) | select(.[0][] | contains($branch)) | "\(.[0]) \(.[1])"')

# Find the latest timestamp
latest_timestamp=$(echo "$branch_image_tags" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -r | head -n1)

# Output the image tags except the one with the latest timestamp
tags_to_delete=$(echo "$branch_image_tags" | awk -v latest="$latest_timestamp" '$2 != latest {print $1}')
#echo $tags_to_delete

image_digests=$(echo "$tags_to_delete" | jq -r '. | join(" ")')
echo $image_digests

for digest in $image_digests; do
    aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name bi-dagster --image-ids imageDigest="$digest"
done
```

When I echo the `image_digests`, I get an output in this format. These are the correctly identified imageTags to be deleted, separated by space.

```
1233-1-DATA 238-1-DATA 157-1-DATA 661-1-DATA
```

But the problem comes when I try to actually delete them. I get this error on the last command.

```
{
  "imageIds": [],
  "failures": [
    {
      "imageId": {
        "imageDigest": "661-1-DATA"
      },
      "failureCode": "InvalidImageDigest",
      "failureReason": "Invalid request parameters: image digest should satisfy the regex '[a-zA-Z0-9-_+.]+:[a-fA-F0-9]+'"
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit:

I create and push these images via Github. For each image, there's an "ImageIndex" and "Image". The "Image" always has a -- instead of the actual name (like in ImageIndex). My code now works to delete the ImageIndex objects but the Image objects are still there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you listed as the image digests output (`1233-1-DATA 238-1-DATA 157-1-DATA 661-1-DATA`) are image **tags** not image digests. Change your code to something like the following:

```
image_tags=$(echo "$tags_to_delete" | jq -r '. | join(" ")')
echo $image_tags

for tag in $image_tags; do
    aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name bi-dagster --image-ids imageTag="$tag"
done
```

Comment: this deleted some items (i.e the ones with artifact type "ImageIndex" but not the ones with artifact type "Image". Is it possible to clean those too?

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to regarding "artifact type". You don't mention that anywhere in your question or refer to anything called "artifact" in your code. Searching for "AWS ECR Artifact Type" and "Docker Image Artifact Type" isn't turning up anything obvious, so at this point it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot in the qs

Comment: It looks like you are querying for images with specific image tags, and then images that aren't being deleted don't have any image tags at all. That seems like more of a process issue on your part, where you aren't adding tags to those images. Obviously you can't delete by image tag if those images don't have tags.